# Font used in a Tikz/PGF figure

Tags: pgfplots, fonts, xetex

I'm using the font Optima for my latex documents. I would like to change the font of the tick label.

I tried to use a new font family and set the global option of tikz, but it doesn't work.

MWE :

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxsf}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Optima}
\setmathrm{Optima}
\setmathsf{Optima}
\setmathtt{Optima}
\setboldmathrm[BoldFont={Optima ExtraBlack}]{Optima Bold}
\newfontfamily\Optima{Optima}
\usepackage[french]{babel}


%TIKZ PGF
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes,tkz-tab}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shadows,matrix,arrows,arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,plotmarks,shapes.geometric,decorations.markings,positioning,calc,shapes.misc,automata,cd,fit,datavisualization,datavisualization.formats.functions,patterns,ipe,decorations.shapes}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11,every axis/.append style={
                    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
                    axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
                    axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
                    xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
                    ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
                    label style={font=\Optima},
                    tick label style={font=\Optima}  
                    }}


%%%
\begin{document}

TEST
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
    xscale = 1,
    yscale = 0.5,
    grid   = major,
    xticklabel=\tick,
    yticklabel=\tick

]
\addplot [
    domain = -5:5, 
    samples= 100,
    color  = red,
]
{exp(-abs(x))};
%\addlegendentry{$f$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `xticklabel=\tick`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have updated my message with the output : the font is now correct but the values get weird.

Comment: Is the font correctly used in normal math stuff (`$123$`) outside tikz?

Comment: Use `xticklabel=\pgfmathparse{int(\tick)}\pgfmathresult,
    yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{0.00001+int(10*\tick)/10}\pgfmathresult`. As implicitly said by @Dr.ManuelKuehner the problem is that it switches to math mode, and your font is not set up to be used in math mode. Either make sure that your font gets used in math mode, too, or use something along the lines of the above. Also please avoid using unrelated stuff , and fix the empty line before the closing `]` in the `axis` environment.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yes, that was my hidden agenda :).